# What is the Salesforce Speedtest

Tags: performance, trailhead

The [Lightning Experience Performance Optimization](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-performance-optimization/optimize-lightning-experience-performance) says, "Measure latency, as well as download and upload speeds, using the Salesforce Speedtest." But no link to this is given and I don't see any reference to it in the Resources section of the unit. I did google for it, but found nothing from Salesforce. Is this a Salesforce feature? What is the unit referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log in to Salesforce, then change the URL to:

```
https://mycustomdomain.my.salesforce.com/speedtest.jsp
```

*(Replace *mycustomdomain* with your Salesforce My Domain name).*

This brings you to a page that tests your Salesforce performance:

[image: Performance Results]

There's no link to it, because one exists for every server; you should use your own local domain.